Can any thinning of a Poisson point process be thinned further into a Poisson point process?
Is the following true? Let $\Phi$ be a homogenous Poisson point process of positive intensity. Let $X$ be a thinning of $\Phi$ where $X$ is stationary and has positive intensity. Then $X$ can be thinned into a homogenous Poisson point process $Y$ of positive intensity.
This question is a specialisation of an earlier one, by adding the assumption of $X$ being a thinning of a homogenous Poisson point process (the thinning process may be dependent, and sophisticated). My intuition (hope?) is that this condition will make it easier to establish $Y$, for if $\Phi$ has intensity $\kappa$ and $\Phi_p$ is an independent $p$-thinning of $\Phi$ then $\Phi_p$ is a homogenous Poisson point process of intensity $p\kappa$.
The assumption of $X$ being stationary and having positive intensity is to handle cases such as the following: Given homogeneous Poisson point process $\Phi$ in the plane, let $X$ be the result of removing all points in the positive $x$-axis half plane.
As a tangible example: Let $X$ be a Matérn hard core point process. Then $X$ is generated from a homogenous Poisson point process $\Phi$ by dependent thinning. Can any Matérn hard core point process be thinned into a homogenous Poisson point process?
